# ASP.NET Core Index.cshtml Redirect to Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-middleware

Assume an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages site with these pages:

- /admin/index.cshtml
- /admin/users.cshtml

I would like to perform some simple redirections to avoid apparently duplicated content.  Below are represented what a request URL would be and what the result redirection should be:

1. /admin -> /admin/
2. /admin/index -> /admin/
3. /admin/users/ -> /admin/users

I would like to perform these redirections from middleware so I don't have to write code for each individual page.  How can I perform the above redirections through middleware?
Case 3 seems like the hardest since the middleware will need to detect if "users" is actually just a page and redirect to the page itself instead of allow the URL to be presented as a non-existent directory (/admin/users/).  (I'm hoping this won't require me to do checks like `System.IO.File.Exists` to see if pages exist.  Hopefully the ASP.NET Core framework can do something more elegant.)

Thank you.

Comment: These redirections should work as described OOTB. You do not have to write code for each page. For example: `return RedirectToPage("/admin");`. That will take you to */admin/index.cshtml*. Can you provide code where they are not working? What is "apparently duplicated content"?

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr, I agree that your scenario works as you described.  I've updated my question a little to clarify.  Consider a request to the URL /admin (no ending slash).  I want it to redirect to /admin/ (with ending slash).  Those two URLs contain the same content, and I want the latter of the two to be the canonical URL.  A more clear example might be /admin/index.  I don't want that URL to be visible.  Instead, I want requests to /admin/index to be redirected to /admin/.

Comment: Gotcha. This is a good question. Unfortunately I am not aware of a way to do that. Hopefully someone else can chime in! Does [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) help?

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr, I've read that page previously, and I don't see any information there that can help with my situation.  Thank you though!